# HTML5/CSS navbar

Tags: css, html, navbar

I want to make a navbar that is a little icon in the corner and when you hover over it a vertical list comes up (the nav bar) of the sites pages however I am not sure how to do this and since I don't know what it would be called I have no way of researching to find tutorials,etc.
Any help would be much appreciated!
thanks
-Ina

Comment: What happens if the user is on a mobile device? They can't hover over it.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @jsve tapping actually fires the hover event too

Answer (score 1):

Here are a lot of examples like what you are looking for:
http://navnav.co/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start looking for tutorials first, then if you dont understand then come here... but its really easy use the css ':hover' function on a html div, and when hovering 'display:block;'

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a dropdown menu. It can be done with pure CSS. Please read this tutorial:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp